# How do I Prolog specify pair printing format

Tags: prolog

Pair data is nice to work with, but I found hard to present. I ask how to accomplish printing a set of vectors such that keys & values line up in a pleasantly. Leading zeros in the pair-values, would help. Sample data:

```
  [1-7,2-43,3-56,4-87,5-110,6-80,7-15]
  [1-1837,2-1873,3-1911,4-1946,5-1975,6-1994,7-2005]
```

I tried to figure out use of SWI format_predicate ; but couldn't.
Then I thought to experiment inline;
       format('~n~w ~w~w~n', ['Pairs: ',1-246,1-2, '    EOL']).

End result should deal with pairs of the form KK-VVVV:

```
01-0007 02-0043 03-0056 04-0087 05-0110 06-0080 07-0015 398 People 7 Gens.
01-1837 02-1873 03-1911 04-1946 05-1975 06-1994 07-2005 Spanning 168 Years
```

Final Answers:

```
fpair(A-B) :- format('~`0t~d~2|-~`0t~d~7| ', [A,B])
applist(_,[]). applist(P,[X|L]) :- Q =.. [P,X],call(Q),applist(P,L).    
dojustone(X):- format('~@ ',[fpair(X)]).    
dolist(X):- applist(dolist,X).
```

Comment: Almost there, your answer resolved the format issue; now I just have to figure out how to apply it to a List of pairs, should be straight forward Prolog problem, but I'm still puzzling out the nesting... In retrospect, a better problem description would have involved a variable element List L of N pairs, each pair to formatted as 2-digit key, and 4  digit value.  The @ was key to the solution. fpair(A-B) :-
    format('~`0t~d~2| ~`0t~d~7|', [A,B]).    gets me:  01 0007 02 0043 03 0056          this expression does NOT work: format('~@ ',maplist(fpair,[(1-246),(1-2),(3-2015)]). mardown next.

Comment: Can you show an example of what you want the output to look like?

Comment: with the 3 definitions,I can do a formated long list of pairs:   applist(_,[]).
applist(P,[X|L]) :- Q =.. [P,X],call(Q),applist(P,L).         
dojustone(X):- format('~@ ',[fpair(X)]).            dolist(X):- applist(dolist,X).

Comment: Here's format predicate & what I wanted:                                         01-0007 02-0043 03-0056 04-0087 05-0110 06-0080 07-0015     398 People over 7 Generations.
01-1837 02-1873 03-1911 04-1946 05-1975 06-1994 07-2005     Spanning 168 Years                                                                            
 fpair(A-B) :- format('~`0t~d~2|-~`0t~d~7| ', [A,B]).                                       (it is hard to properly format this comment!!)

Comment: It would be better to edit your question and put the additional information there, properly formatted.

Comment: You can answer your question. After all, it is worth commenting: `Q =.. [P,X], call(Q)` should be replaced by `call(P,X)`. By why not use the idiomatic `maplist(P,L)` for the same purpose?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use a @ specifier for complex formats, it allows to output specific terms. For instance

```
?- format('~s~n~@~n~@~n~w~n', ['Pairs: ',fpair(1-246),fpair(1-2), '    EOL']).
```

that is, fpair/1 is an user predicate, called by @, capturing its output.

To get fixed width fields, I use the tab specification, built from *two* specifiers working together. Finally, to prefix with 0s, I would use

```
fpair(A-B) :-
    format('~`0t~d~6| ~`0t~d~12|', [A,B]).
```

Without knowing a priori the maximum number of digits, we must use a guess. I used 6 here.

Comment: I think the format control sequence `~\`` is specific to SWI Prolog. At least it's not in GNU Prolog. It might be worth noting, as it's not clear what version of Prolog the OP is using.